# Forget password and account recovery

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-accounts

Why Stack Exchange does not send your previous password to your email (when you forget it)? 
(Instead it gives you a recovery link and you have to change it again.)

Comment: Sending user passwords in cleartext to email is [extremely insecure](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure), and should **never** be done.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if they're doing security well, they probably don't even *have* your password. They have some cryptographic hash of it. (Or if you're authenticating your account through another service, such as google, they wouldn't really have access to it in that case *either*).

Comment: I don't see why there's a close vote here. It's a really bad idea, but it is *absolutely* about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriately asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) since it is not specific to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Exchange do not store your password, so they can't send it to you even if they wanted. (Source: [a series of tweets by Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/722370639005401088))

If a site sends you your password by email, it is unadvisable to trust them with anything of value.